# How to convert List elements to it's super type?

Tags: java, collections, casting

Assume I have the following:

```
class MyType<T> {
    // ...
}

private void test() {
    Set<MyType<? extends Serializable>> in;
    Set<MyType<Serializable>> out; 
}
```

then the following assignment is illegal: `out = new HashSet<>(in);` also `out.addAll(in)` is illegal,
because it cannot be implicitly converted. The following however is completely legal:

```
out = new HashSet<>();
for (MyType<? extends Serializable> s : in) {
    out.add((MyType<Serializable>) s);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this in Java 7 without using an add-loop or dirty/uncheckable casts?

Comment: `out = new HashSet<>(in);` is legal. I don't know why you think it isn't.

Comment: the same goes for me @Eran

Comment: Why not trying out.addAll(in); ?

Comment: try addAll() method

Comment: @EmreAcar that would also work, but still redundant. `out = new HashSet<>(in);` works, and calls `addAll(in)`

Comment: Just realized that my reduced example isn't fully showing the problem. While new HashSet(in) causes the error, addAll() - which causes an error in my real code - does not here. I'll update the example.

Comment: "The following however is completely legal:" It should generate a warning.

Comment: No warning here. Please keep in mind that I am using Java 7, things might be different in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more elegant way to do this in Java 7 without using an add-loop or dirty/uncheckable casts?

No, because you're doing something which isn't type safe.

You're trying to treat a `MyType<? extends Serializable>` as a `MyType<Serializable>` - which it's not: a `MyType<Serializable>` is a `MyType<? extends Serializable>`, not the other way around.

For example, a `MyType<String>` is a `MyType<? extends Serializable>`, but it's not a `MyType<Serializable>`.

Unless you can provide a method on the `MyType` to do the cast (and you'll have an unchecked cast there), or otherwise provide a method to give you a `MyType<Serializable>` from a `MyType<? extends Serializable>`, you will just have to live with the unchecked cast elsewhere.

---

You haven't defined any methods on `MyType`, but let's say it's got a getter and a setter:

```
class MyType<T> {
  T field;
  void set(T field) { this.field = field; }
  T get() { return field; }
}
```

Now, let's assume that you've got this code:

```
MyType<String> str = new MyType<>();
```

If you cast this to a `MyType<Serializable>`, then you can invoke the setter with anything that implements `Serializable`:

```
MyType<Serializable> ser = (MyType<Serializable>) str;
ser.set(Integer.valueOf(0));
```

You're in trouble now, because:

```
String got = str.get();
```

will throw a `ClassCastException`.

The cast you claim is "absolutely safe" is not. It is only safe if there are no consumer methods on the class which take a parameter `T`; and the compiler doesn't consider the existence of any methods to determine if something is type safe.

As such, this cast should generate a warning; if it doesn't, well, that doesn't mean it is actually safe, it just means that either the compiler didn't consider this case, or you are suppressing the warning.

Comment: This is not an up-cast, this is a down-cast. In the case of extends an object can always be safely down-casted to the type it extends. I.E. `Object o = (Object) anythingElse;` is always allowed, because everything extends Object at some point.

Comment: Sure, it's *allowed*, but it's not *safe*.

Comment: It is absolutely safe. At no point will any object cause an issue if it is down-casted to a super type. This is the fundamentals of OOP.

Comment: @TwoThe it's not safe, and the compiler is giving you a very strong indication of that by refusing to compile.

Comment: The example loop compiles just fine without any errors.

Comment: @TwoThe please see example of why it's not "absolutely safe".

Comment: You are confusing what the compiler is trying to cast here. Let's name your `MyType<String>` class A and `MyType<Serializable>` class B, the compiler now complains correctly, that you cannot cast A to B, even though the sub-types could possibly match, because A and B are entirely different classes. If you write MyType<? extends Serializable> instead of String it magically works, because those are now the same types with different sub-types, they are both class B so to say.

Comment: "If you write MyType<? extends Serializable> instead of String it magically works" There is nothing magic about it: you can't invoke a consumer method on that passing anything other than literal `null`, which can be cast to any type without `ClassCastException`, so you the problem described above cannot happen. This is the whole point of bounded generics.

Comment: Long story short: you are explaining something that is interesting, but not relevant to my question. Please stay with the initial question.

Comment: @TwoThe I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/1651107)  is answer Andy is trying to point out

Comment: There is a very important difference between MyType<String> and MyType<? extends Serializable> that renders this whole answer invalid.

Comment: @TwoThe There's a very important difference between `MyType<Serializable>` and `MyType<? extends Serializable>` (i.e. the former can be used safely as a `MyType<Serializable>`; the latter cannot), and *that* is exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: There is - obviously - a difference between that as well, but that particular difference has nothing to do with what you describe here.

Comment: A more detailed explanation:
`MyType<Serializable>` is internally converted to class A, while `MyType<String>` is internally converted to class B as it has a different sub-type. A and B are not compatible as A is not a super-type of B, the ancestors of sub-types are ignored at this point. `MyType<? extends Serializable>` is internally converted to class A with a broader definition of the _same_ sub-type as A. Class A is compatible to itself. The only difference is that the generics checker will accept less types for the specific class, but this is just a compile-time check

Comment: @TwoThe ` If you write MyType<? extends Serializable> instead of String it magically works` Change `MyType` to `HashSet` as being used in the question and try to add something to it by calling `set.add("hello")`. And you will see that it not so magically won't compile.